# How to store iframe website cookies in parent website (chrome and microsoft edge)?

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, cross-site

I have a website (child) within another website (parent). The child website presents a login page initially which uses passport.js for authentication. The issue I am facing is that the parent does not store the cookies from the login and whenever I refresh the parent website, it takes me back to the child login page.

I do not have this issue in firefox but am experiencing it in chrome and microsoft edge.

From my research, I have tried these configurations for session parser but to no avail.
(sameSite: 'none' / false, secure: true)

sessionParser.js

```
...
function setupSession(isSecure) {
  let store = new MemoryStore({ checkPeriod: 86400000 });
  let sessionConfig = {
    name: 'sid',
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    store,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'none',// also tried false but still does not work
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
    }
  };
  return session(sessionConfig);
}
```

app.js

```
...
let app = express();
...
app.enable('trust proxy');
...
app.use(sessionParser);
...
```

What am I doing wrong? (using node v18.16.1, express v4.18.2)